# Status bar could not find cached time string image. Rendering in-process

Tags: ios, swift4.1, xcode9.3

I get the above runtime message after I upgraded to Swift4.1 and Xcode 9.3. Before the upgrade I did not have this message in my console window.

> Status bar could not find cached time string image. Rendering in-process.

comes up every few minutes as long as I have the App running.

It sees to me there is no negative side effect, my App is running, as usual, I have not seen any problems.

I use the standard Status Bar, have not changed to modify it in any way.

**Question 1:** Would there be a problem originating from this warning under situations i have not come across yet?

**Question 2:** Does anyone know how I can get rid of this warning?

Comment: Strange. I am getting this too after upgrading my test device to iOS 11.3 and Xcode 9.3

Comment: I'm getting this too, so far it appears to be harmless.

Comment: Its happening once a minute (for me at least) just after the time rolls over into the new minute.

Comment: Its happening in my case as well but no issues found till now related to performance etc. It seems like an Xcode bug, going to create a ticket about it BTW. As per my understanding if it is an Xcode bug then it will not create any issues to your project.

Comment: i have the same issue too after updating to swift 4.1

Comment: Same to me ;) with Xcode 9.3 and Swift 4.1

Comment: same problem with Xcode 9.4 beta

Comment: I am running my app on Device (iPhone 6 capacity 16 GB available 5.48 gb) and I have also seen this warning but when I got this message in Xcode console log my app got stuck.

Comment: There's nothing in the message itself to suggest that it's flagging an error or warning condition. More the kind of thing that gets put in to help development, and left in even when it's no longer required.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

#### This bug/debug note is present in iOS SDK bundled with Xcode 9.3+

Update: ***not** fixed in Xcode 9.4.1 (9F2000)*
Update: ***not** fixed in Xcode 10 (10A255)*
Update: ***not** fixed in Xcode 11 betas*

I think you can safely ignore it. New versions of iOS/macOS sometimes contain informational debugging messages, and they generally get removed at the next release.

Comment: I will wait for the stable release - at least we get this sorted out finally. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: This bug is NOT fixed in the 9.4 (9F1027a) release

Comment: Not fixed in Version 9.4.1 (9F2000)

Comment: @LalKrishna's comment is inaccurate. Just tested with XCode 9.4.1 on iOS 11.3.1 and 11.4, it occurred on both. At least while using a physical iPhone 6

Comment: I hope Apple with release Xcode 10 with this kind of error fixed.

Comment: Version 10.0 beta 4, not fixed

Comment: folks this is most likely an uikit bug (or feature)

Comment: I don't this is a feature, it should be a **debug info**. I have edited the answer. Please upvote if you found useful. @AntonTropashko

Comment: I have upvoted long long ago. But am now reconsidering.

Answer (score 13):

Same issue was occurring for me too. To overcome this, I did this

Goto Target -> Deployment Info -> Unchecked 'Hide status bar'

This one resolved my issue.
For me, this was the 'Deployment Info' setup.

[image]

Comment: I tested with the checked and the unchecked 'Hide status bar' option. Neither option did prevent the message _'Status bar could not find cached ..... '_ coming up again every other minute.

Comment: Did you check info.plist is there anything added related to Status Bar?

Comment: I have nothing in the info.plist related to the Status Bar. I am using the default Status Bar.

Comment: Can you plz share, xcode version, and device, in which you r getting this? And also, do ur app supports landscape?

Comment: I am using Xcode 9.3 (9E145) and have this issue when using iPad Air 2 and iPhone 8. Yes the App supports landscape and Portrait orientation.

Comment: Can you please stop orientation once, and check?

Comment: Switched to Portrait only - message still comes back and then switched to Landscape only and message comes back again.

Comment: For me, its coming only if I check ‘Hide status bar’. Let me check with other settings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168445/discussion-between-mac-eric-and-sroy).

Comment: The warning disappear when I have View controller-based status bar appearance set to True in the plist

Comment: Thanks for the tip but unfortunately this doesn't work for me either. The message come up again.

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me, actually, it was unchecked at first, I checked it and run and then unchecked again and it worked

Answer (score 1):

I am also seeing this warning appear, and in answer to Question 1, **I am also seeing potentially very nasty behaviour associated with it.**

Running something close to a basic sample animated triangle Metal app, but with

```
renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .load
```

such that the frame isn't cleared every frame.  What seems to be happening is that every other time the warning message is logged, iOS also gets some part of its management of graphics state confused so that I witness a violent flashing of parts of the image (which then goes away again later).

How likely this situation would be to emerge in a 'real' app I'm not sure, but it's definitely not something you want users to end up seeing.

I haven't fixed the problem here thus far; 'Hide status bar' and 'Requires full screen' settings don't help.

Comment: Of course you can;'t fix it. You have your metal state. Apple has it's GLES state for rendeing statusbar and these two apparently collide. File a bug with them proviging a sample app to help them out sort it out on a real world case. This might not surface with vanilla uikit users such as myself.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was hiding navigation bare by

`self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false`

When you are hiding the navigation bar, it hides status bar too!. just use

`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true`

instead. And you will have your status bar back.

Comment: Why does the first line have `= false` and the second `= true`? Are you trying to confuse the reader, or is there a purpose. (If there's no purpose, please correct and write `true` or `false` on both lines.)

Answer (score 0):

To answer Question 2 drawing upon PeterT answer that addresses Question 1:
not only you can not get rid of this warning, but you *mustn't*, cause it means that the underlying problem is anything, but benign. At least in some
scenarious.

This also means that the DEC Field Circus Engineer dance
swapping the wheels that flat in meta info for the project
would rightfully make you look like a clown.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get rid of this warning, by checking the "Requires Full Screen" in *Target-> Deployment Info*.

Checking this option may have some side-effects in iPad, so you should do it having this in mind.

Comment: I am using 'Requires Full Screen' but the message is still coming up