# Status bar rendering warning in Xcode 9.3

Tags: ios, xcode9.3

I updated Xcode to 9.3 and now, I see this warning always popping up in debug area for every minute.

> Status bar could not find cached time string image. Rendering
>   in-process.

Does anyone know how I can get rid of this warning?

Comment: its the bug in xcode 9.3 >

Comment: see this for e.g , https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/99804

Comment: This has been asked already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49586341/status-bar-could-not-find-cached-time-string-image-rendering-in-process) and [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/99804) link on same. So this is a duplicate question please wait for the answer or any update.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**This bug is present in XCode 9.3, also it is resolved in 9.4 beta.**

Update: Bug not fixed in Xcode 10.0

So the choice is your. Either you can wait for 9.4 official release or can use beta for now if you really need to get rid of this warning.
..

Comment: Marking it as correct for verifying it in Xcode beta 9.4

Answer (score 1):

I got the same warning, I fixed by going in to the info.plist and set status bar style to Transparent black style (alpha of 0.5) due to that my back ground is dark.
So far the warning disappear, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is an acknowledged bug in 9.3, discard it for now as a fix for it should be in the next update.

Hope this helps!